# Terraform string computing

Tags: terraform

How is it possible to compute a string in Terraform like this Powershell script?

```
$RabbitMqClusterString = ""
for($i = 0; $i -lt $databaseReplicasCount; $i = $i + 1)
{
    $RabbitMqClusterString += "cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.$($i+1) = rabbit@rabbitmq-$i`r`n      "
}
```

The result should be the following one by looping n times (here 3 times):

```
  cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.1 = rabbit@rabbitmq-0
  cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.2 = rabbit@rabbitmq-1
  cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.3 = rabbit@rabbitmq-2
```

The goal is to insert it into a config map.

```
"rabbitmq.conf" = <<-EOT
  cluster_name = rabbitmq    
  ${rabbitmq_cluster_string}
  #cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.1 = rabbit@rabbitmq-0
  #cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.2 = rabbit@rabbitmq-1
  #cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.3 = rabbit@rabbitmq-2
EOT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [locals](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals), [join](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/join), [for loop](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) and [index](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/index_function)  :

```hcl
locals {
  databaseReplicasCount   = ["first", "second", "third"]
  rabbitmq_cluster_string = join("\n", [for entries in local.databaseReplicasCount : "cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.${index(local.databaseReplicasCount, entries) + 1} = rabbit@rabbitmq-${index(local.databaseReplicasCount, entries)}"])
}

output "rabbitmq_cluster_string" {
  value = local.rabbitmq_cluster_string
}
```

Output :

```
  + rabbitmq_cluster_string = <<-EOT
        cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.1 = rabbit@rabbitmq-0
        cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.2 = rabbit@rabbitmq-1
        cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.3 = rabbit@rabbitmq-2
    EOT
```

In your code :

```
"rabbitmq.conf" = <<-EOT
  cluster_name = rabbitmq    
  ${local.rabbitmq_cluster_string}
EOT
```

Comment: Thank you Will, that helped me a lot finding the solution I was seeking: ${join("\n", [for i in range(0,var.databases.replicas_count) : "cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.${i + 1} = rabbit@rabbitmq-${i}"])}

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on using the `rabbitmq.conf` file elsewhere, you could use a combination of [`local_file` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file.html) and a templated file. The templated file would look something like this (saved at the same level and with a name `rabbitmq.conf.tftpl`):

```
cluster_name = ${cluster_name}
%{ for i in range(0,3) ~}
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.${i} = rabbit@rabbitmq-${i}
%{ endfor ~}
```

Then, in the `local_file` resource, you would also use [`templatefile` built-in function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile):

```
resource "local_file" "rabbitmq" {
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/rabbitmq.conf.tftpl",
    {
      cluster_name = "rabbitmq"
    }
  )
  filename = "${path.module}/rabbitmq.conf"
}
```

The output would be the `rabbitmq.conf` file with the configuration you want:

```
  # local_file.rabbitmq will be created
  + resource "local_file" "rabbitmq" {
      + content              = <<-EOT
            cluster_name = rabbitmq
            cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.0 = rabbit@rabbitmq-0
            cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.1 = rabbit@rabbitmq-1
            cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.2 = rabbit@rabbitmq-2
        EOT
      + content_base64sha256 = (known after apply)
      + content_base64sha512 = (known after apply)
      + content_md5          = (known after apply)
      + content_sha1         = (known after apply)
      + content_sha256       = (known after apply)
      + content_sha512       = (known after apply)
      + directory_permission = "0777"
      + file_permission      = "0777"
      + filename             = "./rabbitmq.conf"
      + id                   = (known after apply)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot finding the solution I was seeking: ${join("\n", [for i in range(0,var.databases.replicas_count) : "cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.${i + 1} = rabbit@rabbitmq-${i}"])}